# Exception with python requests

Tags: python, exception, python-requests

I use requests to manage a connection to a service and I'd like to catch exception if happens.
Then I call my function

```
resp = osTicket.send_ticket(json_message)
print resp
```

which contains

```
def send_ticket(self, data):
        """send tickets to osticket"""

        headers = {"X-API-Key": self.api_key}

        try:
            r = requests.post(self.url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
            return r.raise_for_status()
```

but unfortunately, return is None, exception is not catched.

Answer (score 0):

If an exception gets raised, nothing will be assigned to `r`, so you can't call methods on it.

Exception is likely caught properly.

Comment: but I need to catch the exception and return the error message.

Comment: Then you can return the exception contents - something like `except RequestException as e: return e`. Or better - let the exception propagate to the place where you know how to handle it.